# The requested module 'franc' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, github, npm

I am trying to use franc package but everytime i try to run it this error appears " The requested module 'franc' does not provide an export named 'default' " and i don't know what it means. I've tried changing the filename to mjs or adding "type"="module" in package.json but that only gives me this error, I can't find any solution online.

Note: --experimental-modules does not work( it says '\302\226 npm': command not found)

**This is the js file(i added "type"="module" to package.json)**

```
import franc from 'franc';
console.log(franc('Hi, I speak english!'));
```

**This is package.json**

```
{
  "name": "curs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "franc": "^6.0.0",
    "lang": "^0.1.1"
  }
  
}
```

PS: Ignore lang my point is just to make franc run in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the package has no export like `export default ...` but you are trying to import it like if it had. Indeed, when you provide a name without surrounding curly braces, it means that you want to import a default export and give it your own name.

The library you are trying to import actually has an export like this `export function franc() { //... }`, so you need to import it like this:

```
import { franc } from 'franc';
```

Comment: Thanks that actually helped me. I've started learning node.js only a few days ago and it appears that the course that i am learning from is slighty outdated.

Comment: Glad it helped!